# page reloads on changing the radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, virtuemart

I'm working on a checkout process on a site. i wrote a piece of code to handle the steps, using java script and session storage. session storage keeps the current step. i wrote a function to stay on the same step on reloading the page.

it works fine, but there is two radio buttons on one of steps that user can choose the payment method using them. when user chooses one of them, page reloads but the function doesn't get called. :/  this is the function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (sessionStorage.checkoutstepHolder > 0) {
        cartButtonHandler("onLoad");
    }
});
```

the question is, **why the function gets called on reloads caused by refreshing, but not on reloads caused by choosing the radio buttons?**

maybe the radio button doesn't reload the page, maybe its doing something else :/

Comment: include all your code. so we can help you easly

Comment: No. Not all code. Please create a minimal working sample that depicts issue

Comment: should i or should not include all of my code? i think there is something wrong with `jQuery(document).ready(function()`

Comment: You should include the relevant pieces, enough so we can start to help

Answer (score 0):

I would use a seperate function for this, because you use it on multiple occasions.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ReloadFunction();
});

function ReloadFunction() {
    if (sessionStorage.checkoutstepHolder > 0) {
        cartButtonHandler("onLoad");
    }
}
```

On radiobutton change:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#radiobuttonID', function(){
    ReloadFunction();
});
```