# how to make an event listener execute last in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Two or more event listeners are listening to a radio button.

How can i make one of them execute the last?

```
 jQuery(document).on('change', '#payment_id_2', function(){
     location.reload();
 });
```

This the event listener that i want to be executed the last.

I don't know where are the other event listeners to put them first.

Comment: Add a `setTimeout` inside the handler

Comment: Are these other handlers making any async call?

Comment: The best solution here depends on the reason *why* you need this event handler to execute last. A callback would seem to be the best pattern to use here though - either on an async request or a previous event handler

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951921/page-reloads-on-changing-the-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout but i think its a bad practise to let the browser wait like this. Since this is in async though i dont think there is another way of doing it.